# Random Number Script Is not looping

Tags: python, loops, random, numbers, typeerror

> for y in (random.randint(0,9)) in (x):
> TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable

```
import random
x = (random.randint(0,9))
print (x)
y = (random.randint(0,9))
print (y)
for y in (random.randint(0,9)) in (x):
    if (y)==(x):
        break
```

Comment: Exactly what are you trying to do? `for y in (random.randint(0,9)) in (x):` can't work. https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp

Comment: Im trying to get Y to get a new number until it equals X

Answer (score 0):

what does `(random.randint(0,9)) in (x)` means?

You try iterate over int/number. You need to create an iterable object to loop over it like list, tuple, range etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to iterate until `x==y` you should use a `while` loop. `for` loops iterate over a sequence.
You could do something like

```py
import random
x = (random.randint(0,9))
print (x)
y = (random.randint(0,9))
print (y)
while y != x:
    y = (random.randint(0,9))
```

In general do not put assignations inside conditions (we are not in C!)